# How to label-encode comma separated text in a Dataframe column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, encode

I have dataframe(df) that looks like something like this:

| Shape | Weight | Colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Circle | 5 | Blue, Red |
| Square | 7 | Yellow, Red |
| Triangle | 8 | Blue, Yellow, Red |
| Rectangle | 10 | Green |

I would like to label encode the "Colour" column so that the dataframe looks like this:

| Shape | Weight | Blue | Red | Yellow | Green |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Circle | 5 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Square | 7 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Triangle | 8 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Rectangle | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Is there an easy function to do this type of conversion ? Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["Colour"] = df["Colour"].str.split(r"\s*,\s*", regex=True)
x = df.explode("Colour")

df_out = (
    pd.concat(
        [df.set_index("Shape"), pd.crosstab(x["Shape"], x["Colour"])], axis=1
    )
    .reset_index()
    .drop(columns="Colour")
)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
       Shape  Weight  Blue  Green  Red  Yellow
0     Circle       5     1      0    1       0
1     Square       7     0      0    1       1
2   Triangle       8     1      0    1       1
3  Rectangle      10     0      1    0       0
```